# Presenting text data with playN

Tags: playn

Ok, I already noticed that adding image layers in playN is very easy. But is there a good framework for presenting text data? Or it's totally not what was playN built for? I was wondering if I could present my text in a table. Is that eaisly achieveable or recquire some hacky workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlayN is a game framework and as such very much oriented towards graphics.

You can draw text on screen quite easily, but it is drawing text. PlayN is not designed to do text-processing. Typically, you draw text to an ImageLayer and then continue working with it, essentially turning it into an image.

You can do (limited) text layout with the TextFormat class (http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/TextFormat.html), but again it is limited and mainly focusing on turning the text into a picture as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Triple Play](https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay)? It's described as "a collection of game-related utility classes that can be used with the PlayN library on all of its myriad platform targets" and includes a UI toolkit with a [TableLayout class](https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay/blob/master/core/src/main/java/tripleplay/ui/layout/TableLayout.java).

Comment: wish I could get the demo working. Project cloned from git won't build :/